# How to detect password-protected PDF files during multi-file upload in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, passwords, password-protection

I'm working on a feature in PHP that allows users to upload multiple files at once. Among these files, there could be PDF files. I want to implement a check to see if any of these PDF files are password-protected. If a PDF file is password-protected, I want to display an error message. How can I achieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

i found a similiar post on the web check it out.

http://drupal.org/node/843516

```
/**
* Check whether pdf is encrypted or password protected.
* @param <type> $form
* @param <type> $form_state
*/
function pdftest_is_encrypted($form,&$form_state) {    
     include_once 'sites/all/libraries/fpdi/pdf_parser.php';    
     foreach($form_state['values']['files'] as $value) {
       //Check whether file type is pdf and confirm the file is selected to remove.
        if($value['filemime'] == 'application/pdf' && $value['remove'] != 1) {
          $pdf = new pdf_parser($value['filepath']);                   
          if(stristr($pdf->errormsg,'File is encrypted')) {
              form_set_error('field_attachment', t('Uploaded PDF Document '.$value['filename'].' is encrypted and can not be uploaded. '.l('Guide to troubleshooting failed uploads.','http://support.scribd.com/forums/33627/entries/24412')));
          }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have tested this method but it's not working fine. please tell me any other method.........